# Fredholm $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. A vector subspace $W\subset B(H)$ is called a Fredholm subspace if there is an upper bound for the absolute value of  Fredholm index of all Fredholm operators $T$ in $W$.

> Is there a classification of all $C^*$-algebras $A$ which admit an irreducible representation $\phi:A \to B(H)$ in some Hilbert space $H$ such that $\phi(A)$ is a Fredholm subspace of $B(H)$?

> Is there a classification of all $C^*$-algebras $A$ which admit a faithful  representation $\phi:A \to B(H)$ in some Hilbert space $H$ such that $\phi(A)$ is a Fredholm subspace of $B(H)$?

One can consider the terminology "Fredholm algebra" for any such $C^*$-algebras.

**Edit:** We add an example according to comment by Yemon Choi.

Put $H=\ell^2$ let $S$ be the shift operator on $\ell^2$ and $n$ be a fixed integer. Then this is a finite dimensional Fredholm subspace of $B(\ell^2)$:

$$\{P(S)\mid \text{P  is  a polynomial of degree at most n}\}.$$

Comment: Do you have an example of a Fredholm subspace?

Comment: @YemonChoi Trivial examples: Finite dimensions. Or in the case of infinite dimension, the scalar 1 dimensional space. or any subspace which does not contain any fredholm operator. As another example the space of $\{P(s)\mid s\text{ is the shift operator, whose index is -1 and P is an arbitrary polynomial of degree at most n\}$

Comment: $\{P(s)\mid s\text{ is the shift operator, whose index is -1}\}$

Comment: and P is an arbitrary polynomial of degree at most  n

Comment: How do you exclude the trivial 1-dim rep for the first question?

Comment: @YCor  Good point! one may add "non trivial representation"

Comment: Oh, but actually this trivial 1-dimensional rep doesn't always exist... maybe my comment was stupid. I see no reason in particular to single out the trivial 1-dimensional rep among all finite-dimensional irreducible reps.

Comment: @YCor   I do not know. by definition,  if we consider the zero representation on $H=\mathbb{C}$ as an irreducible representation. any way why should be worry about it? what do you mean by "but actually this trivial 1 dimensional representation does not exist". I think the question is clear, do you agree?

Comment: Actually I especially amended my comment. So, for the first question, this class contains all C$*$-algebras that admit a nonzero finite-dimensional representation, i.e., admit a nonzero finite-dimensional quotient.

Comment: No, irreducible is clearly defined (=nonzero and no proper nonzero closed invariant subspace). "Trivial" is slightly more ambiguous since it can be the trivial irrep (1-dimensional), or any trivial representation (which can be in dimension 0, 1, or more).

Comment: @YCor  Yes I see. Any way as you said every algebra with finite dimensional quotien is  a  fredholm algebra.

Comment: But your questions give two definitions of Fredholm C$*$-algebra. Which one of the two questions is supposed to characterize them?

Comment: @YCor   apart from these cases. it would be  interesting to find some  non examples.

Comment: @YCor  The first one. Please see the answer by Nik Weaver.

Comment: @YCor  Thanks for your recent edit of my question. But there is a  question in my mind since many years ago. Some times a user  edit my post. When I look at his edit I realize that some words is  edited without any change. for example in the second paragraph you changed "algebras"to again "algebras". What is the reason for this situation?

Comment: @YCor  However I am not sure I am convinced by answer of  Nik Weaver. I should rea his answer again.

Comment: @YCor  Any way one can consider both properties with two different name. But it seems that the irreducible one is more interesting(and less obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ has an irreducible representation $\phi$ such that every Fredholm operator in $\phi(A)$ has index 0.

To see it, let me first repeat something from Nik Weaver's previous answer: if $\pi$ is a representation of $A$ such that $\pi(A)$ intersects the compact operators trivially, then any Fredholm operator in $\pi(A)$ is actually invertible.

Now to prove my claim, observe that we may assume that $A$ is simple (up to replacing $A$ by $A/I$ where $I$ is a maximal, proper, closed two-sided ideal). Now let $\phi$ be any irreducible representation of $A$. If $\phi$ is finite-dimensional, then the result is clear and was already mentioned. If $\phi$ is infinite-dimensional then $\phi(A)$ intersects the compacts trivially because of simplicity, so Nik's observation above applies.

Comment: Where is the assertion located in Nik Weaver's answer (or thread of comments)? (anyway I think it's true)

Comment: The proof I can think of: (1) if $A\in B(H)$ is Fredholm and has nonzero index, then either $A^*A$ or $A^*A$ is Fredholm, self-adjoint $\ge 0$ and non-invertible. (2) in a $C^*$-algebra, if $M$ is self-adjoint invertible $\ge 0$ then $M^{-1}\in C^*(M)$. Indeed, approximate $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ by polynomials on the spectrum of $M$. (3) If $N$ is self-adjoint $\ge 0$, Fredholm and non-invertible then $N$ is invertible in restriction to the orthogonal of Ker$(N)$, say with inverse $N'$, extended to $0$ on Ker$(N)$, by (2) $N'\in C^*(N)$. So $I-NN'\in C^*(N)$ is nonzero of finite rank.

Comment: @YCor: denote by $q$ the quotient map to the Calkin algebra. If $x\in\pi(A)$ is Fredholm, then $q(x)$ is invertible in the Calkin algebra, hence also in $q(\pi(A))$. As $q$ is injective on $\pi(A)$, the element $x$ is also invertible in $\pi(A)$.

Comment: Ah OK; actually I wasn't aware of this fact that if an element $M$ is invertible in the big $C^*$-algebra then it's invertible in the smaller one, and could only check it ((2) above) under special assumptions.

Comment: @YCor My favorite reference is Proposition 1.3.10 in Dixmier's $C^*$-book.

Comment: Ah, this proposition boils down from general case to (non-negative) self-adjoint case, for which (B2 in Appendix B) it send to the book Rickart, General theory of Banach algebras.

Comment: @AlainValette  Thank you very much for your answer. Does every $C^*$ algebra admits an irreducible representation  $\pi:A \to B(H)$  such that  $A/\ker \pi$ is simple? I think we need to this statement to apply your proof.

Comment: Moreover I think that you use the fact that for every liminal $C^*$ algebra every irreducible representation is necessarilly a finit dimensional representation. yes?

Comment: @AlainValette I just realize that the last part of my previous two comment was not necessary since your argument  is giving a complete answer to my question. So your argument also gives a complete answer to the whole question of my previous two comment. Thank you again for your attention to my question and your answer.

Answer (score 6):

There's a trivial answer to the second question: every C${}^*$-algebra has such a representation. Wlog assume $A \subseteq B(H_0)$ for some Hilbert space $H_0$, then represent $A$ on $H_0 \otimes l^2$ by tensoring everything with the identity on $l^2$. All the Fredholm operators in this representation have index $0$ (in fact they would have to be invertible).

Comment: could you please explain the reason that why a fredholm operator $T\otimes Id$ must be invertible?

Comment: Sure, if $T$ has nonzero kernel then $T\otimes I$ has infinite dimensional kernel and hence is not Fredholm. Same for cokernel, so if $T\otimes I$ is Fredholm it must have no kernel or cokernel (and have closed range), which means it must be invertible.

Comment: A fancier reason is that anything nonzero in $A\otimes I$ is noncompact, so factoring out the compacts embeds $A$ in the Calkin algebra $Q(H_0\otimes l^2)$. And Fredholm in $B(H_0\otimes l^2)$ is equivalent to being invertible in $Q(H_0\otimes l^2)$.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a representation such that $\phi(A)$ is a Fredholm space then every Fredholm operator there has index zero, because $ind(T^n) = n\ ind(T)$.

Comment: Is not possible that $T$ has a dense range but $T\otimes Id$ would be surjective? I think this situation is not considered in your answer, am I right?

Comment: I don't understand this question. By definition, the range of any Fredholm operator is closed. If $T$ is not surjective then neither is $T\otimes I$.

Comment: I think the closed range is a redundant condition. But why the surjectivity of $T\otimes I$ imply that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: For surjectivity are you using the fact that  $H\otimes K$ is simillar to $hom(H,K^*)$? Then $T\otimes I$ is seen as "compositi9n with $T$? But in infinite dimension, are not some non algebraic (topological) obstractions?

Comment: If an operator has fonit dimensional kernel and finite codimensional range then its range is automatically closed. One can find this fact in many references. The remaining part of my previous comment was a suggestion for proof of your statement that surjectivity(or even fredholmness) of $T\otimes I$ implies that $T$ is surjective(fredholm). I guess that your argument is based on Identifocation of tensor product space with Hom space. Right? So my comment said are you considering purely algebraic structures or you consider topological one?

Comment: Any way i think that  $T\otimes I$ or $I\otimes T$ (or both) are highly non Irreducoble( according to the first part of my question).

Comment: Consider the operator of multiplication by the sequence $(1/n)$, acting on $l^2$. What is its kernel? What is the codimension of the range? Is the range closed?

Comment: ... so I'd be interested in these "many references" that say this cannot happen.

Comment: The sequence of sequences $1/n(log(n)^k$ perhaps shows your map has infinite codimension. But i convonce you close range is redundant in case of banach space

Comment: So multiplication by 1/n is not fredholm

Comment: @Ruy  Very interesting point, thank you!

Comment: @NikWeaver: Since this post has just popped up on the front page again: It is indeed true that if the range of a bounded linear operator between two Banach spaces has finite co-dimension, then it is closed. A reference is, for instance, Murphy's "$C^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory", namely the discussion on the bottom of page 23, along with Theorem 1.4.7 on page 24. (More generally, if a Banach space $Y$ is the (algebraically) direct sum of two operator ranges, then both operator ranges are closed; this is a consequence of the open mapping theorem.)

Comment: (But of course, this is not really relevant for your answer; I just thought it might be a good idea to point this out anyway.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck oh, you are right.  I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  I would like to thank you and NiK Weaver for your attention to my comments.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  yes This situation is interesting: despite of existence of  non closed subspace of  finite codimension, the range of every  Fredholm operator is necessarilly a closed subspace.